# kendo grid for angular 2 - focus lost from filter input on keypress

Tags: angular, filter, kendo-grid

I created a kendo grid component where the focus on filter text field is lost in each key press. My component is like below -

```
    <kendo-grid [data]="getKendoRecords()"
                [skip]="kendoGridPageDataSkip"
                [pageable]="true"
                [pageSize]="getPageSize(options)"
                [navigable]="true"
                [resizable]="true"
                [filterable]="true"
                [filter]="filter"
                [selectable]="{enabled: true, checkboxOnly: true }"
                [kendoGridSelectBy]="'record'"
                [selectedKeys]="kendoSelectedItems"
                (cellClick)="gridCellClick($event)"
                (selectedKeysChange)="onSelectedKeysChange($event)"
                (pageChange)="kendoPageChange($event)"
                (filterChange)="applyFilter($event)"
                >
      <kendo-grid-checkbox-column *ngIf="hasCheckbox()" width="45" showSelectAll="true" [resizable]="false">
        <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate>
          <input class="k-checkbox" id="{{'selectAllCheckboxId_' + options.listId}}" kendoGridSelectAllCheckbox
                 [state]="selectAllState" [disabled]="isReadOnly()"
                 (selectAllChange)="onSelectAllChange($event)">
          <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="{{'selectAllCheckboxId_' + options.listId}}"></label>
        </ng-template>
      </kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
      <kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let property of selectedView.properties" 
                         field="{{getKendoFieldName(property.propertyName)}}"
                         title="{{getKendoFieldName(property.propertyLabel)}}"
                         [filterable]="isSearchableProperty(property, options)"
                         [minResizableWidth]="30">
        <ng-template kendoGridFilterCellTemplate let-filter let-column="column">
          <kendo-grid-string-filter-cell [column]="column" [filter]="filter" [showOperators]="false" operator="contains">
            <kendo-filter-contains-operator></kendo-filter-contains-operator>
          </kendo-grid-string-filter-cell>
        </ng-template>
         <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate>
           {{property.propertyLabel}}
         </ng-template>
         <ng-template *ngIf="getKendoEditorType(property)=='date'" kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
           {{getKendoRecordValue(property, dataItem) | date:formatDate()}}
         </ng-template>
         <ng-template *ngIf="getKendoEditorType(property)=='time'" kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
           {{getKendoRecordValue(property, dataItem) | time:formatTime()}}
         </ng-template>
         <ng-template *ngIf="getKendoEditorType(property)=='boolean'" kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
           <input class="k-checkbox" type="checkbox" [checked]="getKendoRecordValue(property, dataItem)" [disabled]="true" />
           <label class="k-checkbox-label"></label>
         </ng-template>
         <ng-template *ngIf="getKendoEditorType(property)!='date' && getKendoEditorType(property)!='boolean'" kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
           {{getKendoRecordValue(property, dataItem)}}
         </ng-template>
       </kendo-grid-column>
       <ng-template kendoPagerTemplate let-totalPages="totalPages" let-currentPage="currentPage">
         <kendo-pager-prev-buttons></kendo-pager-prev-buttons>
         <kendo-pager-info></kendo-pager-info>
         <kendo-pager-next-buttons></kendo-pager-next-buttons>
         <kendo-pager-page-sizes *ngIf="options.displayPageSizeSelector" [pageSizes]="pageSizeOptions"></kendo-pager-page-sizes>
       </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid>
```

And the code file is -

```
    import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
    import * as _ from 'lodash';
    import { PropertyType, MessageType } from '../../../entity-common';
    import { ListService, LabelService } from '../../../app/services';
    import { EntityListHelper } from '../../../helpers';
    import { PageChangeEvent, SelectAllCheckboxState } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
    import { Map } from 'immutable';

    @Component({
      selector: 'mgr-entity-list-kendo-grid',
      templateUrl: './entity-list-kendo-grid.component.html',
      providers: [EntityListHelper]
    })
    export class EntityListKendoGridComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
      @Input() options: any;
      @Input() endpoint: any;
      @Input() formReadOnly: boolean;
      @Input() selectedView: any;
      @Input() multiSelectValue: any;
      @Input() selectedAllPages: any;
      @Input() multiSelectField: any;
      @Input() inlineAddAction: any;
      @Input() inlineEditAction: any;
      @Input() multiAddAction: any;

      @Output() lookupSelectedEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
      @Output() multiSelectIdsEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

      multiSelectIds: Array<number> = [];
      kendoSelectedItems: Array<any> = [];
      PropertyType = PropertyType;
      MessageType = MessageType;

      newItem: any = { rowProperties: { editMode: false }, record: undefined };
      isSorting: boolean;
      collapsed = false;

      multiSelectSeparator = ';';

      searchParams = {
        Criteria: [],
        AdvancedConditions: ''
      };

      public checkboxOnly = false;
      public mode = 'multiple';
      public mySelection: number[] = [];
      public selectAllState: SelectAllCheckboxState = 'unchecked';
      public kendoGridPageDataSkip = 0;
      public pageSizeOptions = [];
      public filter: any;

      constructor(
        private listService: ListService,
        private labelService: LabelService,
        private helper: EntityListHelper,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.setupBase();

        if (this.options.displayPageSizeSelector) {
          this.pageSizeOptions = [5, 20, 50, 100, 200];
        }
      }

      ngOnChanges() {
        this.multiSelectIds = [];
        this.selectedAllPages = [];
        this.kendoSelectedItems = [];
        this.selectedView = this.helper.getSelectedView(this.options);
        this.options.formLayout = this.selectedView ? this.selectedView.formLayout : null;

        this.setupBase();
      }

      private setupBase() {
        if (this.options.actions) {
          this.inlineAddAction = this.options.actions.find(action => action.action === 'inlineAdd');
          this.inlineEditAction = this.options.actions.find(action => action.action === 'inlineEdit');
          this.multiAddAction = this.options.actions.find(action => action.action === 'newFromLookup');
        }

        if (this.multiSelectIds.length === 0) {
          this.selectAllState = 'unchecked';
        }
      }

      getCount(): number {
        if (this.options.records) {
          return this.options.totalCount;
        }
        return 0;
      }

      isReadOnly() {
        return this.options.readOnly || this.formReadOnly;
      }

      hasCheckbox(): boolean {
        if (this.options.actions &&
          this.options.actions.length > 0 && !this.options.disableRowSelector) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }

      rowClick(item) {
        if (this.multiSelectField) {
          this.updateMultiSelectItems(item);
          return;
        } else if (!this.options.rowClickAction) {
          return;
        } else if (this.options.rowClickAction.action.toLowerCase() === 'selectlookupvalue') {
          this.lookupSelectedEvent.emit(item);
        }

        this.options.rowClickAction.actionFunction(item);
      }

      // multiSelect logic
      updateMultiSelectItems(item) {
        if (this.multiSelectIds.indexOf(item.record.id) === -1) {
          this.addMultiSelect(item);
        } else {
          this.removeMultiSelect(item);
        }

        this.multiSelectIdsEvent.emit(this.multiSelectIds);
      }

      addMultiSelect(item) {
        if (this.multiSelectValue !== '') {
          this.multiSelectValue += this.multiSelectSeparator + ' ';
        }

        this.multiSelectValue += item.record[this.multiSelectField];
        this.multiSelectIds.push(item.record.id);
      }

      removeMultiSelect(item) {
        this.multiSelectValue = this.multiSelectValue.replace(item.record[this.multiSelectField], '');
        this.multiSelectValue = this.multiSelectValue.replace(this.multiSelectSeparator + ' ', '');

        this.multiSelectIds.splice(this.multiSelectIds.indexOf(item.record.id), 1);

        if (this.selectedAllPages.indexOf(this.options.page) >= 0) {
          this.selectedAllPages.splice(this.selectedAllPages.indexOf(this.options.page), 1);
        }
      }

      multiSelectAllCurrentPage() {
        if (this.selectedAllPages.indexOf(this.options.page) === -1) {
          this.selectedAllPages.push(this.options.page);

          for (let i = 0; i < this.options.records.length; i++) {
            if (this.multiSelectIds.indexOf(this.options.records[i].record.id) === -1) {
              this.addMultiSelect(this.options.records[i]);
            }
          }
        } else {
          this.selectedAllPages.splice(this.selectedAllPages.indexOf(this.options.page), 1);

          for (let i = 0; i < this.options.records.length; i++) {
            if (this.multiSelectIds.indexOf(this.options.records[i].record.id) >= 0) {
              this.removeMultiSelect(this.options.records[i]);
            }
          }
        }

        this.multiSelectIdsEvent.emit(this.multiSelectIds);
      }

      onListFilterSearch() {
        this.options.filterListFunction(this.searchParams);
      }

      getPageSize(options): number {
        if (!options.displayPageSizeSelector) {
          return options.pageSize;
        }

        return this.helper.getLookupPageSize(options);
      }

      getKendoRecords() {
        const totalCount = this.getCount();
        return {
          data: this.options.records,
          total: totalCount
        };
      }

      getKendoRecordValue(property, item) {
        const properties = property.propertyName.split('.');
        let object = item ? item.record : this.options.records[0].record;

        for (let i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
          if (!object) {
            break;
          }
          const propertyValue = properties[i];
          object = object[propertyValue];
        }
        return object;
      }

      getKendoEditorType(property) {
        switch (property.propertyType) {
          case (this.PropertyType.string):
            return 'string';
          case (this.PropertyType.checkbox || this.PropertyType.radio || this.PropertyType.boolean):
            return 'boolean';
          case (this.PropertyType.integer || this.PropertyType.number):
            return 'numeric';
          case (this.PropertyType.date):
            return 'date';
          case (this.PropertyType.time):
            return 'time';
          default:
            return 'string';
        }
      }

      getKendoFieldName(property) {
        return property.replace(/\W+/g, '');
      }

      cellClickHandler({ sender, rowIndex, columnIndex, dataItem, isEdited }) {
        if (!isEdited) {
          sender.editCell(rowIndex, columnIndex, this.createFormGroup(dataItem));
        }
      }

      private createFormGroup(dataItem: any): FormGroup {
        const newFormGroup = {};

        this.selectedView.properties.forEach(property => {
          newFormGroup[this.getKendoFieldName(property.propertyLabel)] = this.getKendoRecordValue(property, dataItem);
        });

        return this.formBuilder.group(newFormGroup);
      }

      formatDate() {
        if (!this.options.fieldFormats) {
          return '';
        }

        return this.options.fieldFormats.dateFormat.toUpperCase().toString();
      }

      formatTime() {
        if (!this.options.fieldFormats) {
          return '';
        }

        return this.options.fieldFormats.timeFormat;
      }

      gridCellClick(event) {
        if (event.dataItem.rowProperties && event.dataItem.rowProperties !== null) {
          this.rowClick(this.getRecordItembypageIdLink(event.dataItem.record.id, event.dataItem.rowProperties.pageIdLink));
        } else {
          this.rowClick(this.getRecordItem(event.dataItem.record.id));
        }
      }

      getRecordItembypageIdLink(id, pageIdLink) {
        return this.options.records.find(item => item.record.id === id && item.rowProperties.pageIdLink === pageIdLink);
      }

      getRecordItem(id) {
        return this.options.records.find(item => item.record.id === id);
      }

      public onSelectedKeysChange(event) {
        this.multiSelectIds = this.kendoSelectedItems.map(record => record.id);
        this.multiSelectIdsEvent.emit(this.multiSelectIds);

        const len = this.multiSelectIds.length;

        if (len === 0) {
          this.selectAllState = 'unchecked';
        } else if (len > 0 && len < this.options.records.length) {
          this.selectAllState = 'indeterminate';
        } else {
          this.selectAllState = 'checked';
        }
      }

      public onSelectAllChange(checkedState: SelectAllCheckboxState) {
        this.multiSelectAllCurrentPage();

        if (this.multiSelectIds.length > 0) {
          this.selectAllState = 'checked';
        } else {
          this.selectAllState = 'unchecked';
        }
      }

      public kendoPageChange(event: PageChangeEvent): void {
        this.kendoGridPageDataSkip = event.skip;
        const pageSize = event.take;

        if (this.kendoGridPageDataSkip === 0) {
          this.options.page = 1;
        } else {
          this.options.page = (this.kendoGridPageDataSkip / pageSize) + 1;
        }

        const pageEvent = { pageIndex: this.options.page, pageSize: pageSize };

        this.options.paginateFunction(pageEvent);
      }

      public isSearchableProperty(property) {
        return property &&
          property.propertyType === PropertyType.string &&
          !property.prohibited &&
          this.options &&
          this.options.filterListFunction &&
          typeof this.options.filterListFunction === 'function';
      }

      public applyFilter(event: any) {
        this.filter = event;
        this.searchParams = {
          Criteria: [],
          AdvancedConditions: ''
        };

        if (!event.filters || event.filters == null || event.filters.count === 0) {
          return;
        }

        let filters: any;
        let key: string;
        let value: string;
        let operator: string;
        const conjunction = 'AND';

        event.filters.forEach(filter => {
          key = this.getKendoFieldName(filter.field);
          value = filter.value;
          operator = filter.operator;

          if (operator === 'contains') {
            value = '*' + value + '*';
          }

          filters = Map([[key, value]]);

          const newSearchParams = this.helper.createSearchParams(filters, conjunction);

          this.searchParams.Criteria = this.listService.mergeCriteria(this.searchParams.Criteria, newSearchParams.Criteria);
          this.searchParams.AdvancedConditions = this.searchParams.Criteria.map((r, index) => {
            return index + 1;
          }).join(' ' + conjunction + ' ');
        });

        this.onListFilterSearch();
      }
    }
```

Everything works fine except in each key press the focus is lost from the filter text box. While filtering the system is going back to server and fetches the filtered data.

My first goal is to keep the focus on filter field so that user can continue typing.

Second goal is not to go to server in each key press, rather call the server when user presses enter or tab or lost focus from the input field.

Please feel free to ask if further clarification is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I got a workaround in this scenario. In case it helps someone..

I used KeyDown instead of KeyPress..

Also changed few more in .ts file -

used keydownfilter event -

```
keyDownOnFilter(event: any) {
  if (event && (event.keyCode === 9 || event.keyCode === 13)) {
    this.filterGrid();
  }
}

filterGrid() {
  this.onListFilterSearch();
}
```

Removed the onListFilterSearch command from applyFilter method, cause I dont need to filter on each keydown.. only when Tab or Enter is pressed then the grid will filter data.

Thanks